# Is bumblebee still relevant for Ubuntu 14.04 and up?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I've seen some posts announcing native Nvidia Optimus support since 14.04. But I've also found many tutorials of how to install and run bumblebee on this very same distribution.

So my question is... is bumblebee still required in order to properly use and alternate between my laptop's discrete and dedicated graphics cards or I should expect them to work as intended out-of-the-box?

What exactly do they mean by "native support"?

Comment: Apprently, it is not necessary anymore (everything is now integrated in the proprietary nvidia drivers and their config tool). On the other side, this tool provided by nvidia is (in my opinion) infinitely more complicated then typing "optirun" when I want to run something with my dedicated card. So, on 14.10 I'm still happy using bumblebee :)

Answer (score 0):

It is in the NVIDIA Settings which is installing with the nonfree driver, but I don't switch often to compare performance.