# Which applications should I open with Bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Having a Nvidia-optimus laptop, I have, on recommendation, installed the Bumblebee optimization. Though I am unclear about when to actively use it.
There seems to be a a GUI called Bumblebee GUI where you can configure what should be run through Bumblebee.

But what applications or what kind of applications should I open with bumblebee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimus is a technology from nVidia that allows you to switch between the lower power Intel graphics that are integrated in your CPU and the higher power nVidia graphics from your discrete graphics card. The big difference between Optimus and other strategies is that even when using the discrete card to do the computations, it still pipes the actual display data through the integrated Intel graphics to your monitor.

There's no set rule for which card to use for what program. In general, you should run demanding applications such as games, modelling software, and GPU optimized programs (e.g. bitcoin miners) using the nVidia Card. The only advantage of using the Intel graphics is that it consumes less power. So first try running it using the Intel graphics; if your performance isn't good enough, restart the program using nVidia graphics. See also the help article [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Comment: What about VLC? Or playing videos in firefox?

Comment: Added more detail to my answer. I would expect the Intel to do fine with anything in VLC and most things in Firefox. If it doesn't, just restart the program using your nVidia card. Or, if you don't care about power consumption, just use the nVidia card whenever you have any doubt which to use.

Comment: Great, and I guess the same goes for how much heat is emitted?

Comment: The discrete card would likely generate more total heat. However, in terms of maximum temperature, I'm not entirely sure. It's possible the more powerful nVidia card would get hotter. Or it's also possible the Intel graphics would get hotter since it's on the same physical chip as the Intel CPU which is also generating heat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for Ubuntu 14.04 there is native NVIDIA support for Optimus - named Prime:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/more-work-to-support-nvidia-optimus.html

There is also some indicator app to help the process:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

So, instead of configuring applications lists you could just switch video cards and run whatever app you want on whatever card is active then.

Comment: I can't find any information concrete information as to how stable and how well this actually works. See this thread; http://askubuntu.com/questions/501772/is-bumblebee-still-relevant-for-ubuntu-14-04-and-up

This is the most summarizing information I can obtain; http://swapniel99.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/bumblebee-or-nvidia-prime/